# Django: One-to-Many and Many-to-One Serializers and Queries

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a relationship similar to this:
One city has one-to-many buildings; one building has zero-to-many devices.

The user must be able to request a city by its PK, receiving in response the city, the buildings in the city, and the devices in those buildings.

I know that foreign keys are necessary in creating the models, like this:

```
class City(models.Model):
    #Columns here

class Building(models.Model):
    cityId = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #Columns here

class Device(models.Model):
    buildingId = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #Columns here
```

What I'm having trouble with is how to write the serializers and the queries. As of now, my serializers only include fields corresponding to that table's columns:

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['id', ...]

class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = ['id', 'cityId', ...]

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['id', 'buildingId', ...]
```

However, when I have to respond to a GET request for the city, I only know how to use a nested for loops to get the building and device data after finding the city by the inputted ID. I presume there's a better way, but I'm having trouble finding clear answers online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use related_name keyword in your models, you can learn more about it -- here is how it works--

1. Define you models and add related_name to the foreign keys as -

   ```
   class City(models.Model):
        ##fields

    class Building(models.Model):
        cityId = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='abc')

    class Device(models.Model):
        buildingId = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='xyz')
   ```
2. Then define your serializers in reverse order and add the related_name of models in your serializers field--

   ```
    class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Device
            fields = ['id', 'buildingId', ...]

    class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        xyz = DeviceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Building
            fields = ['id', 'cityId', xyz ...]

    class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        abc = BuildingSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = City
            fields = ['id', 'abc' ...]
   ```

Now when you will try to get the city, you will get all the building rel;ated to that city and also all the Devices related to each building.

There is one another method called as [serializermethodfield](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), this is of great use in many areas, you can use any one depending upon your choice.

Hope this helps..